# How to programmatically detect if toolbar exists in activity

Tags: android, android-activity, toolbar

I know that question is a bit strange, but I need to detect programmatically if toolbar exists in the screen. Detect it not directly from Activity. For example I have custom view that need to calculate screen properties.

Comment: "I have custom view that need to calculate screen properties" -- "screen properties" is meaningless, since as of Android 7.0, apps may not fill the screen, courtesy of multi-window.

Comment: I understand this, but anyway is it possible to detect not considering that moment with Android 7.0 that you told?

Comment: :: shrug :: Have your custom view ask its hosting activity, "yo, did you set up a toolbar?", I guess.

Comment: That's the best simple way I think )

Answer (score -1):

if i get what did you mean that could help .

```
     `getActionBar().isShowing()`
```